# Can we use Sqoop to move any structured data file apart from moving data from RDBMS?

Tags: sqoop, hadoop2, bigdata

This question was asked to me in a recent interview.
As per my knowledge we can use Sqoop to transfer data between RDBMS and hadoop ecosystems(hdfs, hive,pig,hbase).
Can someone please help me in finding answer?

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, Sqoop can't move any structured data file *(like CSV)* to HDFS or other Hadoop ecosystem component like Hive, HBase, etc.

**Why would you use Sqoop for this?**

You can simply put any data file directly into HDFS using it's REST, Web or Java API.

Sqoop is not meant for this type of use case.

Main purpose of sqoop import is to fetch data from RDBMS **in parallel**.

Apart from that, Sqoop has [**Sqoop Import Mainframe**](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_import_mainframe_literal).

> The `import-mainframe` tool imports all sequential datasets in a partitioned dataset(PDS) on a mainframe to HDFS. A PDS is akin to a directory on the open systems. The records in a dataset can contain only character data. Records will be stored with the entire record as a single text field.